# .mp4 file won't play in the browser, is some weird codec being used?

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, h.264, codec

I'm trying to investigate why a certain video is not playing properly in the browser, you can see here the video compared with a video that works properly, also you can see that on my desktop (OS X), it shows a preview the second video file but not a preview of the first (implicating to me that there is something going on with a codec)

Codec as per VLC of the first video (doesn't work in browser):

[image]

Codec as per VLC of the second video (works fine in browser):[image]

Comparison of the videos on my desktop:

[image]

Comment: Run ffprobe on the files and report.

Comment: Can you post the ffmpeg command used to generate these videos?

Comment: Why don't you share your video files?

Comment: Then two videos have been downloaded I haven't made them, I will post ffprobe info when I get chance (soon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failing video looks like ts container (VLC showing PIDs) with mp4 extension, so even though the codecs themselves are ok, the container format itself is unsupported.
If true, it needs to be remuxed to genuine mp4 container to make it work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, care to check out this question I just put up today? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820722/playing-webm-chunks-as-standalone-video