# Playing webm chunks as standalone video

Tags: video, video-streaming, webrtc, webm, web-mediarecorder

I've built some code that will get the MediaRecorder API to capture audio and video, and then use the ondataavailable function to send the corresponding webm file blobs up to a server via websockets. The server then sends those blobs to a client via websockets which puts the video together in a buffer using the Media Source Extension API.

This works well, except that if I want to start a stream partway through, I can't just send the latest blob because the blob by itself is unplayable. Also, if I send the blobs out of order the browsers usually complain that the audio encoding doesn't match up.

I really don't know as much about video containers, codecs etc as I should to pull this off, but my question is, how can I play those blobs as standalone videos? Can I somehow use code to add the information which is in the first blob (playable on its own) onto the other blobs? What would be a good approach to being able to get  the stream playing partway through? I would transcode but it seems to take too long since I want to set up real-time (or close to) streaming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Only the first blob received from the MediaRecorder API contains a header. So you will need to simply extract it and prepend it to your other blobs to be able to play them as standalone WebM videos. I recommend you to verify whether it works by using tools like hex editor. And you can automate this process on your server.

Comment: @SumanBogati Sorry, I can't find working code. I would recommend you try it manually and verify each chunk is playable as standalone using hex editor. Slice the header and prepend to the next chunk (backend). But I found that this approach is wrong as it starts stacking delays. TCP WebSocket is not for streaming.

Try this approach - RTCPeerConnection. They already made UDP connections for you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection

If it is for production, use Twilio. I was able to build flawless video streaming in 10 minutes. https://www.twilio.com/video

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you please suggest something here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236838/how-to-play-webm-files-individually-which-are-created-by-mediarecorder

Answer (score 2):

With MSE, you can load the first chunk containing the WebM segment with track info and what not, and then start loading a cluster later on.  The browser will figure it out.

WebM clusters begin with timestamps, which enable this to work.

Comment: I got this working on Chrome, but not FireFox. Ended up going another direction and getting Kurento set up as a media server and using WebRTC which has been much easier than fiddling with MSE

Comment: Is MSE the only way to play chuncked webm? Can't we just do like an audio/mpeg http chunked? (which plays fine over simple http)

Comment: @KeyneViana Yes, you can play it straight from a server too.  The question is about data from the MediaRecorder.

Comment: @Brad I'm trying to do exactly this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891897/is-mediasourceextensions-the-only-way-to-play-a-chuncked-webm Mind dropping a line there?