# Send chunks from MediaRecorder to server and play it back in the browser

Tags: node.js, getusermedia, webm

With the following code in NodeJS I'm able to play a webm file served from server:

```
app.get('/video', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200,{
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Cache-Control': 'private',
        'Content-Type': 'video/webm'
    });

    console.log('Http client connected: Streaming!');

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('./small.webm');
    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

Now I want to get the WebM directly from getUserMedia() API. So I used MediaRecorder within Socket.IO:

```
 // Client
 var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
 // ...
 mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
     console.log('Data', e.data);
     chunks.push(e.data);
     socket.emit('data', e.data);
 }


// Server
app.get('/video', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200,{
        "Content-Type": "video/webm",
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    });
    // Add the response to the clients array to receive streaming
    clients.push(res);
    console.log('Http client connected: Streaming!');
});

console.log("Starting server...");

httpServer.listen(9007);

var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Listening...");
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("[data]", data);
        // Actual HTTP audio Streaming
        if (clients.length > 0){
            console.log("[http("+clients.length+")]", data);
            for (var client in clients){
                clients[client].write(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So now I receive the stream back to the browser but I'm unable to play it with:

```
    function getHttpStreaming() {
        console.log("Getting streaming");
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        audio = document.getElementById('video-streaming');
        audio.src = 'https://localhost:9007/video?' + n;
        audio.load();
    }
```

The network tab shows the streaming coming but nothing plays! What am I missing?

**EDITED**

As pointed out by @Brad WebM needs [some special configs](https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Streaming_WebM_to_Icecast_with_FFmpeg) in order to work that doesn't contains in the stream coming from getUserMedia, so I added ffmpeg between the stream and served the ffmpeg output to the browser and the video played! (same on icecast) <s>But is getting very lagged and I do not know why. Also, as a test instead of sending it directly to the browser I've sent it to icecast, but icecast was unable to play it resulting in ffmpeg's broken pipe. In order to send it to the browser I've used:</s>

```
const ffmpeg = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-i', 'pipe:0',
    '-f', 'webm',
    '-cluster_size_limit', '2M',
    '-cluster_time_limit', '5100',
    '-content_type', 'video/webm',
    //'-vf', 'scale=1280:-1',
    '-r', '30',
    '-ac', '2',
    '-acodec', 'libopus',
    '-b:a', '96K',
    '-vcodec', 'libvpx',
    '-b:v', '2.5M',
    '-crf', '30',
    '-g', '150',
    '-deadline', 'realtime',
    '-threads', '8',
    //'-y',
    //'icecast://xxx:xxxx@host:port/live',
    'pipe:1'
]);
```

My output is the following:

```
FFmpeg STDERR: ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

FFmpeg STDERR: Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'pipe:0':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 16.67 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1

FFmpeg STDERR: [libvpx @ 0x21c32a0] v1.5.0

FFmpeg STDERR: Output #0, webm, to 'pipe:1':

FFmpeg STDERR:   Metadata:

FFmpeg STDERR:     encoder         :
FFmpeg STDERR: Lavf56.40.101
FFmpeg STDERR:

FFmpeg STDERR:     Stream #0:0
FFmpeg STDERR: (eng)
FFmpeg STDERR: : Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 2500 kb/s
FFmpeg STDERR: ,
FFmpeg STDERR: 30 fps,
FFmpeg STDERR: 1k tbn,
FFmpeg STDERR: 30 tbc
FFmpeg STDERR:  (default)
FFmpeg STDERR:

FFmpeg STDERR:     Metadata:

FFmpeg STDERR:       alpha_mode      :
FFmpeg STDERR: 1
FFmpeg STDERR:

FFmpeg STDERR:       encoder         :
FFmpeg STDERR: Lavc56.60.100 libvpx
FFmpeg STDERR:
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus (libopus), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libopus
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> opus (libopus))

FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  118 fps=3.6 q=0.0 size=     660kB time=00:00:15.05 bitrate= 359.4kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 0b 03 80 fb 03 3f 22 89 95 18 c5 f0 68 67 7c 25 76 9d b6 e7 b4 2d dc 9c b4 da a3 0c 47 e1 aa ae 3d f2 84 1e 65 08 22 9e a7 af b6 50 7d a2 c7 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  123 fps=3.6 q=0.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:15.65 bitrate= 517.6kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 0d 20 80 fb 03 40 75 4b 59 48 46 42 79 37 d8 44 de f5 ef 7b ec ce 05 c4 44 48 bc 12 6e a2 a9 1e bd 73 59 bc 27 fd ab ec bf a1 8a 32 67 c4 ee ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  127 fps=3.5 q=0.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:16.19 bitrate= 500.4kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 0f 77 80 fb 03 43 f6 ef d2 61 b5 47 bb e9 06 5f 7e 37 eb 58 a5 4d a2 30 ff e1 4c 41 28 90 f1 dd 4f 45 b0 44 5b d2 de c3 85 47 0d d5 36 44 39 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  132 fps=3.5 q=0.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:16.79 bitrate= 482.5kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 11 93 80 fb 03 52 2d 4d 14 48 6c 14 63 aa de e8 14 0f 31 31 c4 13 a5 f6 0b 06 ad a2 e3 99 ec 77 de c7 ae 92 13 73 df 8b 80 25 bc fc 21 14 33 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  136 fps=3.5 q=0.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:17.33 bitrate= 467.5kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 13 73 80 fb 03 40 3a 72 51 05 2d 5e 70 84 92 99 4f 1f 7b 39 05 b9 43 15 d9 a1 47 76 9b cc bf 58 ff dd 2f d7 af f2 56 9a b5 8c 1a af 30 48 f1 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  140 fps=3.4 q=0.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:17.81 bitrate= 454.9kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 15 53 80 fb 03 3f 66 84 ff f2 b9 44 64 c0 ed e4 40 bf e2 43 89 d7 44 4d f1 f7 10 fb 92 a7 1a 20 8a 5a c7 fa 9d ff 8a 83 aa 3f 70 e5 a3 05 00 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  144 fps=3.4 q=0.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:18.29 bitrate= 442.9kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c9 81 17 70 80 fb 83 ff 10 fc 11 43 d3 8f 64 b4 d3 a3 74 c6 87 be c0 94 39 78 a0 8c 12 60 76 cc 0b d5 a4 2e d8 7b ab 59 11 d2 44 bf a2 5a 76 32 04 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  148 fps=3.3 q=0.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:18.83 bitrate= 430.2kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 19 50 80 fb 03 1a 70 8a fe 75 d9 56 19 b3 91 cc 5d 17 d8 4c 29 c0 30 61 37 ae 53 c4 8b 18 a5 bc 74 0c ab 6d 7e 32 cc 8d 89 35 6a a3 3a eb 65 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  152 fps=3.2 q=0.0 size=    1204kB time=00:00:19.31 bitrate= 510.8kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 1b e3 80 fb 03 51 93 d5 35 c0 0b 06 13 d6 b2 67 86 98 1e 4b 8e 72 1d 3a a6 81 09 97 ef f8 d6 c2 b6 1a ee f3 bb c9 f3 3f 16 e8 be d3 d0 90 72 ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  157 fps=3.2 q=0.0 size=    1204kB time=00:00:19.97 bitrate= 493.9kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 1d c3 80 fb 03 44 52 8f e0 6d db 60 9d 43 1d 0e ae dc 9c 0b 94 f8 b0 f1 13 d0 f5 1b b6 f9 8e 2b 0d f6 93 fa d5 99 d9 bb fe b5 29 3d 61 2d bf ... >
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=  161 fps=3.2 q=0.0 size=    1204kB time=00:00:20.45 bitrate= 482.4kbits/s
[data] <Buffer 43 c6 81 20 57 80 fb 03 4f c1 d1 78 88 0c 6b 82 a7 51 3e 65 71 a6 62 07 09 60 6f ce 7c 83 7d 15 4f 4b 46 3e e3 b7 78 49 e5 a7 3d bf e2 37 93 7a 17 1a ...
```

**EDITED2**

Chrome fails to play the icecast video stream with the following errors:

```
00:00:13 736    video_decoder   FFmpegVideoDecoder
00:00:13 736    info    Selected FFmpegVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: vp8 format: 4 profile: vp8 coded size: [640,480] visible rect: [0,0,640,480] natural size: [640,480] has extra data? false encrypted? false rotation: 0°
00:00:13 739    error   Failed to send video packet for decoding: timestamp=24300000 duration=33000 size=201 side_data_size=0 is_key_frame=0 encrypted=0 discard_padding (ms)=(0, 0)
00:00:13 739    error   video decode error
00:00:13 739    audio_buffering_state   BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:00:13 739    pipeline_error  PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE
00:00:13 739    pipeline_state  kStopping
00:00:13 740    pipeline_state  kStopped
00:00:13 731    duration    unknown
```

**EDITED3**

It seems like the chrome problem is related with ffmpeg output. With the following I was able to play the icecast stream both on chrome and firefox:

```
const ffmpeg = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-i', 'pipe:0',
    '-f', 'webm',
    '-cluster_size_limit', '2M',
    '-cluster_time_limit', '5100',
    '-content_type', 'video/webm',
    '-r', '30',
    '-ac', '2',
    '-acodec', 'libopus',
    '-b:a', '96K',
    '-vcodec', 'libvpx',
    '-b:v', '1M',//'2.5M',
    '-crf', '60',
    '-bufsize', '2M',
    '-g', '10',
    '-deadline', 'realtime',
    '-threads', '8',
    '-keyint_min', '10',
    'icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8004/live'
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just needle-drop into the WebM stream.  WebM/Matroska require some setup to initialize the track info and what not.  After that, you'll have Clusters, and you have to start on a Cluster.  Additionally, Chrome is going to require that each Cluster start on a keyframe, which you're not going to be able to guarantee with the data from MediaRecorder.  Therefore, server-side transcoding (or at least, some nasty hacking on the VP8 stream) is needed.

Comment: If I add ffmpeg in between does it works? In this case what arguments should I use in order to generate the desired stream?

Comment: @Valdir This code gets you halfway:  https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example  Lop off the RTMP part and use `-f webm`.  Also, there's no need to write this HTTP Progressive server yourself, Icecast can handle WebM in this fashion, and can directly receive from FFmpeg.

Comment: I've edited the question with the ffmpeg part but I'm getting some lag when sending to the browser and was unable to send to icecast. if you know any tips to solve this, could you  update your answer?

Comment: @Valdir The MediaRecorder API in that example is only going to dump data every second, so there will be lag.  In addition, if you're transcoding server-side, there will be additional lag unless you configure your codec for low latency.  If latency matters to you, you're fundamentally using the wrong technology.  You should use WebRTC instead.

Comment: @Brad, it's actually not latency the problem, but the video suddenly stopping for several seconds and then resuming and stopping again, over and over. Also unable to send the same stream to icecast.

Comment: It seems like my upload speed was way to low. That's the problem... changing connection the video plays more smoothly. But icecast still unable to play it accessing the http streaming url

Comment: I side note, icecast plays it on firefox but not chrome

Comment: @Valdir Check your details at chrome://media-internals to see if there are any clues.  I suspect your WebM Cluster elements aren't starting with keyframes.  Chrome is particularly picky about it.

Comment: @Brad I've added the log on the question from media-internals. Any clue?

Comment: What's the "hack" that must be done? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303618/create-webm-video-blob-from-series-of-arraybuffer

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to key help from [Brad's FB sample](https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example), I was able to put together a working version that sends an audio/video stream to icecast, which then can easily be played back in a browser. Since the audio and video codecs are directly copied, it's only 5 - 10 seconds of lag.

Here's the link:

https://gitlab.com/jamie/icecast-web-source-client

Answer (score 0):

[SFMediaStream](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/SFMediaStream/) could help you splitting media stream into chunk and play it back to the browser, or maybe on the server's speaker for Raspberry. And also adding effect on your stream, it would be fun enough to try the available effects.

```js
//* Broadcaster
var presenterMedia = new ScarletsMediaPresenter(/*{options}*/);

// Send the packet below somewhere
presenterMedia.onRecordingReady = function(bufferHeader){};
presenterMedia.onBufferProcess = function(packet){};

//* Streamer
var audioStreamer = new ScarletsAudioStreamer();
audioStreamer.playStream();

// Receive from somewhere
audioStreamer.setBufferHeader(/* bufferHeader */);
audioStreamer.receiveBuffer(/* packet */);
```

There are some example on the repository if you want more detail on how to use it.