# Handling Media Recorder Blobs in FastAPI WebSocket - Issue with Corrupted Video

Tags: python, websocket, video-streaming, fastapi, mediarecorder

I am working on a project where I'm using FastAPI to handle WebSocket connections for receiving video blobs from a Media Recorder. The goal is to create video parts with a size limit of 5 MB and save them as separate files. The initial part works well, but subsequent parts seem to be corrupted, and I'm facing playback issues.

I've tried to handle buffering and file writing within the loop, and I suspect that the way I'm managing file operations might be causing the corruption. Can someone review my code and provide insights into why subsequent video parts are not playable?

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```js
//frontend
recorder.ondataavailable = (e: BlobEvent) => {
 socket.send(e.data)
}
recorder.start(1000)
```

```py
@app.websocket("/video")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, token: str = Query(...), videoId: str = Query(...), authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    await manager.connect(websocket)

    temp_dir = os.path.join("temp", videoId)
    os.makedirs(temp_dir, exist_ok=True)

    queueNumber = 1
    bufferedSize = 0
    totalRequiredBufferSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024
    
    print(f"{datetime.utcnow()}: Client connected: {websocket.client.host}")
    try:

        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
    
                file = open(os.path.join(temp_dir, f"{videoId}-video-{queueNumber}.webm"), 'ab')

                if bufferedSize < totalRequiredBufferSize:
                    if data:
                        file.write(data)
                        bufferedSize = bufferedSize + len(data)
                        print(f"buffered size = {bufferedSize} and blob size = ${len(data) / (1024 * 1024)}")
                
                elif bufferedSize >= totalRequiredBufferSize:
                    if data: 
                        file.write(data)
                        print(f"End= {queueNumber} and blob size = ${bufferedSize / (1024 * 1024)}")
                        file.close()
                        bufferedSize = 0
                        queueNumber = queueNumber + 1
 

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print(f"Client disconnected: {websocket.client.host}")
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
```

This is how the files are looking :-
[image: Corrupted Files]

I appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to correctly handle file operations within a FastAPI WebSocket loop, especially when dealing with Media Recorder blobs.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to play each segment by itself by just splitting it on an arbitrary byte count? Specific video stream container formats expect explicit headers and an explicit encoding inside the stream itself, such as i-frames - how these segments can be split depends on the container format you're using.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I want to write the incoming blobs on the filesystem with a set of 5 MB each. What would you recommend to do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: That depends on _what your goal is_. Since you're saying that the files are not playable by themselves; do you want to split them into separate video files that are about 5MB in size and can be played separately? Do you want to have each as a invidual video file? Or do you only need to keep them separate and merge them before delivery to a unified binary stream?

Comment: @MatsLindh, so as I am getting blobs from frontend for every second, my end goal is to save the video in real time to AWS storage. So I want to get blobs from frontend and keep saving them in the parts of 5MB each and once each part is equal to 5MB I want to convert that part to MP4 using ffmpeg and keep uploading to AWS S3 using multipart upload

Comment: @MatsLindh, I want to make sure that each part works perfectly and they follow up with the previous part, i.e. if they merge together by AWS, they should form an entire video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is corrupted, it's just that you can't arbitrarily cut a file and expect it to work.  You've cut off all the initialization information.

Additionally, you can't cut on MediaRecorder data event data either.  It's meant to be a continuous stream, and the data event just gives you some convenient sized chunks.... they are not necessarily segments (even though in practice, they basically are).

Each container format has its own way to deal with this.  For WebM, see my previous answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237720/362536

Comment: So instead of dividing the media recorder blobs into separate files, I tried using ffmpeg and stdin the incoming webm blobs and it would covert those into one mp4 file. It was working fine. Do you think its a more reliable option?

Comment: @Aviato Yeah, that's what I do.  And, you can have FFmpeg output proper HLS or DASH segments if you want to stream it rather than just record it.

Comment: is it possible to output parts using ffmpeg? For example, if I process a full video using ffmpeg and edit something on top of the frames using a image processing library, than if I want to save the output as parts instead of a full video on the disk?

Comment: @Aviato Yes, if you use HLS or DASH, you'll get a segmented output as you're looking for.  Alternatively, look at the generic segment muxer in FFmpeg.

Comment: would you please mind providing your feedback on this ffmpeg question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77743310/pipe-video-frames-from-ffmpeg-to-canvas-without-loading-the-entire-video-into-me