# Real time joining base64 .webm video chunks and play without delay or flicker isues

Tags: html, node.js, video, webm

I'm trying to make a live streaming system without P2P connection by nodejs.

Video chunks are recorded each 3 seconds and sent to server via webrtc and they save simply as .wemb base64 files.

But when the client is trying to see the whole video, there is flickering problem.

Each time a 3 secs video ends the src attribute of video tag changes to next chunk.

I tried to save some upcoming ones to a buffer in order to prevent delays, but still it is considerable.

I used MediaSource API to add source buffer but id didn't work on that specific webm encoding either.

The codes are huge and complicated and doesn't help much, but if they are necessary in order to correct the concept I can put then too.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes of course I'm editing. The similar question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820722/playing-webm-chunks-as-standalone-video but without answer.